# mongoose schema design

Tags: javascript, schema, mongoose

I do the following:

```
var peoples = db.model('peeps', new mongoose.Schema());
peoples.find({}, {weights: 1}).exec(function(err, data) {
  // data is an array with objects
  data.forEach(function(el, index, array) {
    console.log(el); // --> {weights: [{weight: 45.78, diet: ln}, {weight: 21.89, diet: lgt}]}
    consoel.log(el.weights) // --> undefined
} ... });
```

But when I suggest a Schema like so:

```
var peoples = db.model('peeps', new mongoose.Schema({
   weights: []
   }));
peoples.find({}, {weights: 1}).exec(function(err, data) {
  // data is an array with objects
  data.forEach(function(el, index, array) {
    console.log(el); // --> {weights: [{weight: 45.78, diet: ln}, {weight: 21.89, diet: lgt}]}
    consoel.log(el.weights) // --> [[object Object], [object Object]]
 } ... });
```

The second then allows me to access the [object Object] by `el.weights[0].weight`

Is this diffence by mongoose design or am I doing something wrong in my first block of code to access the objects in the array?

An example of the schema/data is like this:

```
{ _id: 0,
    spname: 'INDV_748',
    weights:
     [ { weight: 1.463179736705023, diet: 'ln' },
       { weight: 11.78273309957772, diet: 'lgt' } ] }
```

If I don't specify the `_id: Number` in the `new mongoose.Schema({...})`, the `_id` will not show up in any `find()` query for both situations above.

Is this also part of the design?

Comment: This is confusing.  These `find` queries shouldn't be returning any docs with a query selector of `{weights: 1}` since `weights` is an array of objects, not `1`.  And the syntax of your `forEach` calls doesn't make sense.

Comment: edited.  copied over the wrong syntax.  Thanks.

Comment: Seems about what I'd expect; fields that aren't included in the schema don't get full support.  If you don't define `_id` then it's assumed to be an ObjectID which is incorrect in your case.

Comment: is there a reference somewhere?

Comment: The part about the `_id` is [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id), but you're going outside the lines by trying to access fields outside of what's defined in the schema.